# Look out outside or Look outside

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Can it be said like this or Is the second one correct only?

> Look out outside the window
>
> Look outside the window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both those sentences are grammatical (although the first is nonstandard and the second is slightly uncommon), but they have completely different meanings.

---

> Look outside the window.

This means you should turn your gaze outside the window. (From inside the room you are in.)

It is also a common phrase, although not as common as just *look out the window*, and the meaning that would normally be thought of.

---

But the definitions of the noun [**lookout**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/look%20out) and the related verb phrase ***look out*** give different possible meanings:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **lookout** noun
>   **1** : one engaged in keeping watch : WATCHMAN
>   **2** : an elevated place or structure affording a wide view for observation
>   **3** : a careful looking or watching
>        // on the *lookout*
>   **4** : VIEW, OUTLOOK
>   **5** : a matter of care or concern
>
> **look out** verb
>   : to take care or concern oneself —used with *for*
>   // *looking* out for number one

So:

> (Lookout / look out) outside the window.

This could be an abbreviated sentence meaning several different things.

> There's a guard outside the window.
>   There's an observation post outside the window.
>   You need to be paying attention to things while outside the window.
>   There is a view outside the window.
>   There is a matter of concern outside the window.
>   Take care of yourself when you are outside the window.

Those example sentences use a more common construction if any of those meanings are meant.

---

If the first sentence in the question is supposed to *mean* the same thing as the second, then it is an error.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. The correct phrase is "Look out the window".

You can't look "outside the window", because a window is not something that can contain you. You can look outside the car, or outside the house, etc, if you are in those things at the time. Or, you can use it on its own: "Look outside".

Answer (score 0):

You could say “Look outside” or “Look out the window.”

In the former phrase, one is more concerned with the act of looking outside. So, imagine someone who barged into a home and wanted to alert the people inside that something spectacular was happening outside. The person would scream, “Hey, everyone! Look outside!” So, however each one would be able to, they would each scramble to look outside, whether it be by running outside, standing in the open front door, or by opening the window blinds.

In the latter phrase, it is a more specific command directing the person to look outside through the window. It could be that the window is the only means by which the person can see what is occurring outside.

Neither of your two original suggestions are spoken in daily English.